# Hadoop/MapReduce in Java: "Missing .jar library" error even though I've included it

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce

I am getting the error: "Project 'hadoop-project' is missing the required library: home/hadoop/hadoop-common-2.6.0.jar"

Even though I see it listed under "Referenced Libraries".

My hadoop project runs ok except for that the output folder and file is not being created. I think if I was missing that jar I wouldn't be able to run the program in the first place. Here is the error I am getting in the stack trace that shows that the outputs are not being created: "output.fileOutputCommitter.java:setupJob(292)mkDirs failed to create file: ..."

Has anyone seen this error before and know how to solve it?